# PHP Website Converted to Static HTML site - Linking Issue

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, dynamic, static

I had a Dynamic PHP website which I needed to convert into a static website to give to a client.  I used **wget** to pull the files and it did exactly what I needed.  The only problem is..my links before (the ones indexed in google) have no file extension.  I used .htaccess to get rid of the .php file extension.

So one of my URL's would look like this: 
**http://www.domain.com/about/**

When I got a static version of the website, it changed all of my links to .html

That could be fine, as I could use htaccess to get rid of that file extension and so all of my links will be the same as before.  Well, all of the internal linking in each page is linking to the .html version.

**Is there a way with htaccess to direct users if they go to about.html it will take them to about with no extension?  So all of my internal linking will still work?**

Or is there any other suggestions you guys might have on how to handle this?

Here is the wget code I use:

```
wget -k -K  -E -r -l 10 -p -N -F -nH http://www.domain.com/
```

How can I get that to output .php files instead of .html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

taken from: http://www.sicanstudios.com/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  That will work.  One quick question though, I have two forms that need to be .php and not .html.  Do you know how to use Wget at all?  I need to ouput all files as .php instead of .html  - I updated my question with the code I used.

Comment: Well, you're using the `-E` flag which is alias for the `--html-extension` flag, so that is why it is changing filenames to `.html`. If you remove that, it should keep extensions.  However, you won't get php code with wget, so why would you need the .php extensions?

Comment: So I can manually add the PHP snippet to the two pages I need to, and they already have the .php extension so all of the linking through other pages I won't have to change.  Thanks!